# Do i need Bluez when using a bluetooth dongle

Tags: linux, audio, bluez

i am new to Linux and Bluetooth. i know that the standard implementation of the bluetooth protocol stack is bluez. I know that alsa is not supporting bluez anymore and if you want to use audio over bluetooth, you need pulseaudio. so pulseaudio should support HSP/HFP since version 6 and bluez 5.x. Know i was wondering if i can connect a usb-dongle to my hardwareboard (raspberryPi) there is a serial connection to the board. is that right? so the Dongle has the BT-STack and you can use alsa audio over USB like an USB HEadset?

i hope someone can help me.

Comment: If you mean: "I want to plug in a Bluetooth USB Dongle in my Raspberry PI  and want to use the BlueZ stack" then yes, BlueZ supports USB Bluetooth dongles.

Answer (score 1):

The answering this vast addressable question is not that easy. I have few hints which will help you to narrow down.

1. BlueZ is user layer stack to communicate or use the functionality of Linux Kernel Bluetooth subsystem and provides helpers to developers.
2. USB Dongle itself doesn't have any stack and I don't really understand your question in that sense. To brief, USB Bluetooth Dongle is just the hardware device with Bluetooth functionalities. To make it functional, you need Linux Kernel Bluetooth system support enabled and either you can directly make use of "socket" system calls to pair,connect etc., or use BlueZ to develop applications with API's
3. BlueZ itself doesn't provide API's for developers, instead it makes use of the DBus to provide methods, properties and signals with vast range functionalities. Check [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc)
4. If you interested in Audio Playback using Bluetooth, then you should register your media player and audio sink with BlueZ with according media DBus Interfaces.

To add, I am currently developing a framework library to wrap the DBus functionality provided by BlueZ for friendly development of applications. Check this [repo](https://github.com/parthitce/bluetooth-framework) and it is currently in initial development phase.

Comment: GitHub Repo address?  Or is that a JavaScript promise?

Comment: Sorry. The repo in currently not available in GitHub. I was planned to publish it after nice shaped implementation.